# How to properly write a brand, corporations in my report?

Tags: writing, writing-style

I have a lab report where I have to show my results using PSpice simulation software. I take screenshots from my screen to illustrate my results and paste those images inside my report. Below a figure, should the label text be:

1. Figure 1: Schematic using PSpice

OR

2. Figure 1: Schematic using pspice  (without giving attention to the formatting used in the brand name)

What is the most appropriate way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it mandatory to include the registered trademark symbol ® next to the name of a computer program?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/is-it-mandatory-to-include-the-registered-trademark-symbol-next-to-the-name-of)

Comment: Yes, the registered trademark symbol is a duplicate question. I am going to edit the question. But I still don't know how to properly write the software name: Using capital letters or just plainly writting pspice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I take is to look at (1) how the organization formats the name and (2) how other researchers write it. It doesn't make sense to make up your own formatting for it (unless *maybe* the formatting is just excessive).

Usually those two match, so in your case I would write it as PSpice.